# Bridging header not importing Cocoapod libraries, "No such module 'MagicalRecord'"

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop, cocoapods, magicalrecord

I'm trying to import MagicalRecord into a (until now) pure swift project. I've set up Cocoapods, installed MagicalRecord, and I'm using the `.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcodeproj`.

I'm using a bridging header that was created automatically by Xcode when creating an Objective C class (though I've also tried using a manually-created bridging header), and I've ensured that the bridging header setting in the `.xcodeproj` under **Build Settings>Swift Compiler - Code Generation>Objective-C Bridging Header** is correctly set up.

In the bridging header, I have the following

```
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>
```

and then when I try to use `import MagicalRecord` in a swift file, I get an error that states `No such module 'MagicalRecord'`. I've tried different `#import` statements in the bridging header, like importing `CoreData+MagicalRecord.h` like older tutorials have suggested, and it still doesn't work.

It doesn't seem like my bridging header is totally broken, since when I try to import a file made in my own project, it works and I can create objects defined in the imported file. However, if I try importing MagicalRecord in that file, I still get the import error above.

Is there some extra setup that I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Okay wow literally minutes after posting this I tried what I SHOULD HAVE TRIED FIRST, which is just using the methods in MagicalRecord without an import statement. Turns out it totally works! No need for an import statement in Swift. Found the clue to figuring this out here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html. Table in section "Importing Swift into Objective-C" is helpful

Comment: Mine wouldn't work WITHOUT the import statement...Xcode 7 beta...ugh

Comment: I'm in a state where I can access MR_create(), etc, off the managed objects, but I can't call MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack().

Comment: Ah, had to `import MagicalRecord` in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bridging header is in place and `use_framework!` exists in your `Podfile`.